# Find method not working in GMongo using $gt greater and less than operands

Tags: grails, mongodb, groovy, gorm-mongodb

I'm using the GMongo library in Groovy to read items from MongoDB. The CacheItem class is a simple object to hold cache items, and each item has an expiration time which is set at the time when it's added to the mongo. When I read items from mongo, I only want to retrieve items that have not expired based on the expirationMillis field.

```
class CacheItem {
  def _id
  def cacheKey
  long expirationMillis
  def value
}
```

This works for retrieving items using the cacheKey

```
item = mongoDb.cache.findOne( cacheKey: "600")
```

But when I try to use criteria with greater than/less than convention against the expirationMillis, I can't seem to retrieve any documents..

```
long nowMillis = (new Date()).getTime()
item = mongoDb.cache.findOne( cacheKey: "600", expirationMillis: { $gt: nowMillis})
```

Am I using the wrong convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape $gt such that it looks like this:

```
long nowMillis = (new Date()).getTime()
item = mongoDb.cache.findOne( [ cacheKey: "600", expirationMillis: [ "\\\$gt" : nowMillis]]  as BasicDBObject)
```

or

```
long nowMillis = (new Date()).getTime()
item = mongoDb.cache.findOne( [ cacheKey: "600", expirationMillis: [ '$gt' : nowMillis]]  as BasicDBObject )
```

Comment: I tried that, but Eclipse is complaining about the syntax; does not like the semicolon separating '\\\$gt' and 'nowMillis'

Comment: sorry... typo. You should use square brackets instead of curly ones